# Proving the set of all real matrix $3\times2$ with rank $2$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{3\times2}$

Tags: general-topology

I have to prove that the set of all real matrix $3\times2$ with rank $2$, M, is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{3\times2}$.
I do not know how to do it, but trying to prove that $\mathbb{R}^{3\times2}-M$ is a close subset of $\mathbb{R}^{3\times2}$ could be easier.

Comment: If a $3\times 2$ matrix $A$ has rank two, two of its rows are linearly independent. If we change those rows just a little bit, they keep being linearly independent. This "little bit" defines a ball (in whatever matrix norm you are considering).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2301453/the-set-of-rank-two-matrices-in-2-3-matrices-over-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** the rank of $M$ is $2$ iff 
$$
\det(M^TM)\neq 0
$$

Comment: Ok, thank you. I know how to finish from here, but, how can I prove that $rank(M)=2$ implies $det(M^{t}M)$ is not $0$?

Comment: one general result is that $\text{rank }M = \text{rank }M^TM$