# the set of rank two matrices in (2,3) matrices over R .

Tags: general-topology, matrices

How to show the set of rank 2 matrices in (2,3) real matrices is open?
(Sorry for the inconvenience in understanding the terms as I don't know how to write latex.)
I have no idea about the meaning of open set for set of rank 2 matrices.
Can anyone please help me discussing this topic. Thank you.

Comment: Let me get this. You want to show the set of rank 2 matrices in $(2,3) \in \mathbb{R}$ matrices is open? Is this what you are trying to say?

Comment: yes, this is ....

Comment: Do you mean the set of 2 by 3 matrices with real valued entries which have rank of 2?

Comment: yes @mathfan27543

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complement is a closed set, since it is the set of those matrices $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ such that$$\begin{vmatrix}a&b\\d&e\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}b&c\\e&f\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}a&c\\d&f\end{vmatrix}=0.$$

Comment: 'complement is a closed set ', we can say it by the determinant function but we can apply it for square matrices, but here we are given 2 by 3 matrix. how can we say it here? please explain

Comment: sorry sorry I wrote that wrong

Comment: Is it right if i take a function f from the set of all 2 by 2 matrices to R (real numbers set) defined by determinant and then take inverse image of zero. Then we get 2 by 2 matrices whose determinant is zero but we have to get 2 by 3 matrices. please can you help me

Comment: The set that you want to prove that it is closed is $F^{-1}(0,0,0)$, where $F\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\end{smallmatrix}\right)=\left(\begin{vmatrix}a&b\\d&e\end{vmatrix},\begin{vmatrix}b&c\\e&f\end{vmatrix},\begin{vmatrix}a&c\\d&f\end{vmatrix}\right)$.

Comment: The OP wanted to show it's open, not closed.

Comment: The OP wanted a proof of the fact that a certain set is open. I proved that its complement is closed. Do you see anything wrong about this approach?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the map $f: M_{2×3}(\mathbb{R}) → \mathbb{R}^3$
given by sending a matrix to the triple of its $2 × 2$ minors. This is a continuous map.
The set of rank 2 matrices is the inverse image of the set ${(x1, x2, x3) ∈ \mathbb{R^3} | x_1\neq 0, 1 ≤ i ≤ 3}$. This set is open in $\mathbb{R^3}$
, hence the set of rank 2 matrices is open
in $M_2×3(\mathbb{R})$.